# Js beginner calculator. How to make the first string empty in case it's an operator

Tags: javascript

works, but allows the first input to be an operator(+,-,*,/,=). How can I make the first input be number only?

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
```

added a variable to distinguish the operators

```
const operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
```

```
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
});

function calculate(event) {
const clickedButtonValue = event.target.value;
```

tried this, to no effect

```
if (display.value[0] = operator) {
  display.value = '';
}
```

```
else if (clickedButtonValue === '=' && display.value !== '') {
  display.value = eval(display.value)
} else if (clickedButtonValue === 'C') {
  display.value = ''
} else {
  display.value += clickedButtonValue;
}


}
```

Comment: You need `==` instead of `=` in `if (display.value[0] = operator) {`

Comment: use `===` in place of `=` `display.value[0] = operator`. `=` is assignment

Comment: Since `operator` is an array, you probably want to check if your display is included in that array rather than checking equality: `operator.includes(display.value[0])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (display.value[0] === operator) { //changed your = operator to ===
  display.value = '';
}
```

This should work, your problem was that you were assigning display.value[0] to operator instead of comparing them.

Comment: `operator` is an array, so this won't work. (as a side note, for questions where the answer is based on fixing a typo, it is usually recommended to close it as a typo instead of answering)